# Lenovo N500 Overclocking/Upgrade

Tags: cpu, lenovo-laptop, overclocking

I have a Lenovo N500 42336BU laptop and want to know how to overclock it.

Also want to know what CPUs are compatible upgrades to the Intel T3400 in this machine.

Answer (score 1):

> want to know how to overclock it.

You can't, AFAIK.

> Also want to know what CPUs are compatible upgrades to the Intel T3400 in this machine

None, unfortunately.

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt to overclock this machine anyway, even if you could - the N500 is a pretty spotty performer.